# How to exclude duplicates from result set in solr while keeping one item?

Tags: solr, filtering

I am returning results from solr 6.4.1 which items do have certain characteristics.

e.g.

```
color
type
price
```

This is an example dataset

1. **red, house, *40***
2. red, garage, 30
3. green, house, 20
4. **red, house, *50***

Now I want to remove all **duplicates defined by same color and type** from the set, keeping the duplicate with the lowest price.

In the example the dataset 1 & 4 are a duplicate with different price and I want to keep the one with the lowest price in the resultset, because it is the cheapest red house.

Desired result:

```
1: red, house, 40
2: red, garage, 30
3: green, house, 20
```

How can I remove items where attributes define duplicates from the set, keeping one with the lowest price?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest: just bite the bullet and add another field whose value is color+type, then use  [Field Collapsing](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_6/collapse-and-expand-results.html) on that field to group by it,and use 'min price' for the selection of the doc that represents the group:

```
fq={!collapse field=color_type min=price}
```

Comment: That looks like what I am looking for. I tried to implement, but the PHP solr functions are not clear to me (http://php.net/manual/en/solrquery.collapse.php) . This does not work: $this->query->collapse( '{field=color_type min=price}'); Do you know the right syntax for this?

Comment: Right :-) Now I get at least an error for non existing class. "Error loading class 'solr.IntPointField'" - Was this added in 6.5? I am running 6.4.1.

Comment: Sorry, the last reply was for another post. Still trying to get the collapse command implemented via PHP.